# CSS Contact Form not being responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have created a Contact Form, everything looks somewhat fine, the way I want it but having issues. The Form is not being responsive when re-sizing/scale the browser down. I have messed around, I think a little too much with the code to the point that I have no clue what i'm doing or have done. I'm about to lose my mind!

When I re-size the browser, the labels go outside of the container it's in. The submit button is also not centering even when I try `margin: 0 auto;`

I will post the HTML & CSS along with my CodePen below. Thanks for any help!

**CodePen** https://codepen.io/vCoCo/pen/MLReKK?editors=1100

**HTML**

```
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <form id="contactForm" action="contactform.php" method="post">
      <h2> Get In Touch! </h2>

      <div class="details">
        <label for="firstName"> First Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name..." required>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <label for="lastName"> Last Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name..." required>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <label for="email"> Email </label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email..." required>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <label for="textMessage"> Message </label>
        <textarea id="textMessage" name="textMessage" placeholder="Enter Message In Here..." required></textarea>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit Message">

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
/**** GLOBAL ****/
.container{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

/********** CONTACT FORM **********/
#contact{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}

#contact .container{
  width: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#contactForm{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#contactForm h2{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.details{
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;

}

label{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=email]{
  width: 400px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=submit]{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#contactForm textarea::placeholder{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: You using bootstrap or not

Comment: No. Not using Bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the `width` of several elements, you're setting fixed widths and it repercusses on mobile resolutions, also with the overflow of the container it make the childs to hide inside the parent.

A good solution for a responsive mode is to set the widths to 100% of the parent and setting a max width for greater resolutions.

I made a fork of your Codepen.

Important: most of the problem also is, make sure to set the `box-sizing` of global elements. i.e. `* { box-sizing: border-box;}`

Hope this helps.

Codepen https://codepen.io/devlumberjack/pen/rPbMzr?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on how to get the "Submit Message" button in the centre rather than it being on the left?

Comment: An idea might be to set the input to 'Display: block; margin: 0 auto;' that should do the job.

Comment: I didn't know you can add a max-width and width to the same element. For the #contact .container. You added width: 100% and max-width: 500px;

Comment: Of course, it allows you to set a limit of width without setting a fixed one. So for lower screens than 500px, it will be 100%. This might help to understand: https://css-tricks.com/tale-width-max-width/